# First letter in column is Uppercase while selecting by lowercase

Tags: mysql

When I execute this query

```
SELECT b.booking_id, bp.person_id, b.start_date AS start_date
FROM Bookings b
LEFT OUTER
JOIN (
SELECT Booking_id, Person_id
FROM Booking_participants) AS bp ON bp.Booking_id = b.Booking_id
WHERE b.Product_id = '933' AND b.end_date > '2017-01-16 16:50:52' AND b.end_date <= '2017-01-17'
ORDER BY b.end_date
```

It returns the following on one server

[image]

And on another server it will return

[image]

Why is it `person_id` on one server and on the other it's `Person_id`?

Table `Booking_participants`
[image]

Table `Bookings`
[image]

In both servers `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'lower_case_table_names'`
Returns 0

Comment: Not sure of the problem.. but you could may be define your own alias and try? You have `Person_id` in join statement

Comment: Because of [lower_case_table_names](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_lower_case_table_names) and case insensitive file systems.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Aren't these for `Table` names only and not `Column` names?

Comment: @SMA Yeah I thought of that too and already fixed it like that. But I'm just wondering why I see it like this.

Comment: Are both linux servers?

Comment: @Rahi both are linux servers. One is with Directadmin the other one is bare

Comment: @たぬき You're right, I've just tried and I cannot replicate the behaviour, thus it must be something else.

Comment: I see through the images there seems to be a difference in table structure. Did you compare the structures and also foreign relations? [Check image 1 and 2]

Comment: @Rahi I've added 2 extra pictures as you can see they are the same. [Image 3 and 4]

Comment: Why are you worried about it? use aliases and you're done

Comment: I would check the mysql versions then...

Comment: Please [edit] your question and tell us what kind of host (Linux, Windows, MacOs) you use for each of these servers. Also please give the command `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'lower_case_table_names'` on each server and tell us the results.

Comment: "select * from Bookings where bOOkinGs.PROduct_ID = 13,002"

Comment: Also note that in the first instance "Person_Id" has a yellow key next to it indicating a primary key, whereas the second has no key next to it.

Comment: @baao I'm not worried about anything. I've already fixed it by using aliases. I'm just wondering why it happens.

Comment: @denny Using this server one returns `pErSoN_iD` server two returns `Person_id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems likely that your data definition you used on your second server spells the name of your column `Person_id` with an uppercase name. On the first server, it seems likely it was spelled in lower case.

MySQL column names can be stored and rendered in mixed case, but are always processed in a case insensitive way.  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html

Comment: Would it work if I tried: `ALTER TABLE Booking_participants
 CHANGE COLUMN Person_id person_id INT(11) NOT NULL AFTER Booking_id;
` or do I need to specifically drop the table and create it again to make sure it saves it as lowercase for the first time